How can I change or delete the shortcut to shade/roll up a window in Ubuntu 24.04?
There is a keyboard shortcut for IntelliJ products which is Ctrl+Shift+S and it clashes with Ubuntu's "Toggle Shaded Window". the shortcut used to be stored here:
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded

as described here: How can I change or delete the shortcut to shade/roll up a window in Ubuntu 20.04?
However, installing Ubuntu 24.04 and then installing apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
results in this key not being found:
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded
No such key “toggle-shaded”

Therefore, there must be some sort of updated answer for this age-old question.
